# RestKit: How to expire / clear the Core Data cache?

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I'm developing an app that deals with a lot of images / photos / videos sent and retrieved from a server, and i'm using RestKit's Core Data integration as a cache in my iOS app so said media loads faster after it's already been retrieved. However, I want the user to be able to clear the cache and refetch from the server as well. How can I tell RestKit to expire the Core Data cache, either based on a time period or by the user?

Any help is appreciated -- Stack Overflow has been an incredible resource for me, and I am deeply appreciative :-)

Comment: You are saving the media in core data?

Comment: I was going to just save a URL to the local media in Core Data.

Comment: If you want to manually clear the cache, you can delete all the entities. But you shouldn't need to do this, the server response headers should tell RestKit when updates have happened etc. See: [Last-Modified & Cache-Control](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: This cool to know, thanks :-) My app needs to be HIPPAA compliant so I need to expire data often.